# What is this hidden pair of red gloves in Batman: Arkham Asylum supposed to symbolize?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I was playing *Batman: Arkham Asylum* and during my travels, I found this item set locked away behind an unpassable vent bar.

It's a single cell, not available to get, just out of reach.

What is this supposed to reference, or is it just random?

[image]

Here's a zoomed version I took using my Bat Zoom:

[image]

I think that engraving is of Arkham Asylum itself? Who does this belong to?

Found it while playing the game on my PC. It's location on the map is:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's one of the Riddler's items: [the Ratcatcher's equipment](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Ratcatcher#Batman:_Arkham_Asylum).

Comment: How on earth did you find this out?

Comment: Just Googled :) http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=arkham+asylum+red+gloves I have played through the game and got all the Riddles so I must've seen it, but it was a while back.

Comment: You've put an extra 'h' in 'Ratcatcher'... I can't do a 1-character edit unfortunately.

Comment: @jwaddell Fixed it.